# MUI - Remove overlay in Drawer?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use the `Drawer` component and I have noticed that when the drawer is fed the prop `open={true}`, there is a default dimmed overlay on the underlying page / div.

Is there a best-practice Material-approved way to remove the dimming? I have had some partial success with setting the prop `variant={"persistent"}`. This stops the dimming, but it also forces me to add a close button just to close the drawer.

What I am looking for is the drawer to be closable when clicking outside its boundary, and while it is open I would like to have the dimming go away (without resorting to a button to close the drawer).

I have looked at the docs and tried passing the prop

variant={"persistent"}

Which gets rid of the overlay, but now when I click outside the drawer it doesn't auto-close.

```
<Drawer 
open={open}
anchor="top"
onClose={toggleDrawer}
variant={"persistent"}
modal={true}
>
```

I would like to have the dimming go away (without resorting to a button).

Are there any options that are Material - approved? I can try CSS hacks but I don't want to break Material's CSS or have glitchy flashes of overlay.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can add `BackdropProps={{ invisible: true }}`.

Working Example:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import InboxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox";
import MailIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Mail";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  list: {
    width: 250
  }
});

export default function TemporaryDrawer() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    top: false,
    left: false,
    bottom: false,
    right: false
  });

  const toggleDrawer = (side, open) => event => {
    if (
      event.type === "keydown" &&
      (event.key === "Tab" || event.key === "Shift")
    ) {
      return;
    }

    setState({ ...state, [side]: open });
  };

  const sideList = side => (
    <div
      className={classes.list}
      role="presentation"
      onClick={toggleDrawer(side, false)}
      onKeyDown={toggleDrawer(side, false)}
    >
      <List>
        {["Inbox", "Starred", "Send email", "Drafts"].map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem button key={text}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={text} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={toggleDrawer("left", true)}>Open Left</Button>
      <Drawer
        BackdropProps={{ invisible: true }}
        open={state.left}
        onClose={toggleDrawer("left", false)}
      >
        {sideList("left")}
      </Drawer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

Relevant documentation links:

- https://material-ui.com/api/backdrop/#props

  - Documents the `invisible` prop
- https://material-ui.com/api/modal/#props

  - Documents the `BackdropProps` prop of `Modal`
- https://material-ui.com/api/drawer/#import

  > The props of the `Modal` component are available when `variant="temporary"` is set.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I will look over it and respond ASAP.

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked. I should add that I didn't even have to specify the variant="temporary" part for the Backdrop to be invisible. I left the variant unspecified (default).

Comment: Yes, since "temporary" is the default `variant`, leaving `variant` unspecified (as is the case in my example) is equivalent to setting it explicitly to "temporary".

Comment: the only solution that worked if you still want to close the drawer on outside click

Answer (score 6):

In **later versions** of Material UI you can just use the following:

```
<Drawer
 hideBackdrop
>
```

Comment: This however disables closing Drawer on clicking outside of it (as Backdrop is hidden, cannot catch that click). The accepted answer is better solution.

Comment: Yes it does, thank you for the clarification. In my case I didn’t need to close it by clicking the outside, so it this was cleaner. But the accepted answer is best if you need that functionality. Cheers.

Comment: this way don't allow interaction page when the swipeable is open if we want interact with our page while the swipeable is open you should add the code : 

ModalProps={{
        slotProps: {
          root: { 
            style: {
              position: "absolute",
              top: "unset",
              bottom: "unset",
              left: "unset",
              right: "unset",
            },
          },
        },
      }}

Answer (score 3):

```
ModalProps={{
    hideBackdrop: true,
  }}
```

That solved the problem for me :)

It removes the whole backdrop thing and you are free to press whatever you want or the same button you opened it to close it :)

Answer (score 3):

For MUI 5+ Drawer (temporary):

```
<Drawer
      PaperProps={{
        style: {
          //style props for your drawer menu here
        },
      }}
      ModalProps={{
        slots: { backdrop: "div" //override the backdrop component },
        slotProps: {
          root: { //override the fixed position + the size of backdrop
            style: {
              position: "absolute",
              top: "unset",
              bottom: "unset",
              left: "unset",
              right: "unset",
            },
          },
        },
      }}
    >
```

Comment: this style allow interaction page ! Is good for the case  and is good way !

Answer (score 1):

It appears they deprecated the use of `BackdropProps` in the newer versions. I was able to remove the background and keep the 'collapse on click away' event using `slotProps` instead like this:

```
<SwipeableDrawer
      open={isOpen}
      onClose={() => {
        setIsOpen(false);
      }}
      onOpen={() => setIsOpen(true)}
      slotProps={{
        backdrop: {
          invisible: false
        }
      }}
    >
```