# Highlight background Element using material-ui dialog component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using a dialog component in V4 of material-ui, and I want to keep a particular element from darkening in the background.

I want the darkening, just not for the button that I click, and I was wondering if this was possible?

Comment: I'm not too sure I understand the question, but is this not something that can be solved with CSS?

Comment: When I click the button to bring up the pop-up, the background darkens, and those elements are "disabled". Those elements are still there, you just can't interact with them. I would like to just not darken the button...

Comment: I've used the dialog myself, and buttons have not disabled themselves

Comment: @Sasha The buttons aren't technically disabled, but the backdrop prevents them from being interacted with while the dialog is open.

Comment: That is usually a dialogs purpose, the dialog takes up the whole screen, setting the button `z-index` mght work but i'm not sure

Comment: It is possible to make the entire backdrop invisible (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58020202/material-ui-drawer-component-can-i-remove-overlay-it-adds/58021443#58021443), so that there is no darkening of the content behind the dialog, but there isn't a way to prevent darkening of specific elements while still darkening others except by making the backdrop invisible and controlling all darkening that gets applied yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working for me is using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58020202/material-ui-drawer-component-can-i-remove-overlay-it-adds/58021443#58021443) post's answer of using `BackdropProps={{ invisible: true }}` and manually adding the `filter: brightness(60%)` function on the other components.