# Drawer Component Backdrop blocking users from interacting with page will it is open

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I have a Drawer Component anchored at the bottom but I would still like to interact with the page above the drawer but either I can click out of if but the drawer closes so I tried the variants persistent and permanent both didn't work they actually made it so nothing at all happens when I click out of if. I think it has something to do with the spacing or padding above, but if anyone knows how to disable that, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58020202/material-ui-drawer-component-can-i-remove-overlay-it-adds

Comment: I viewed that post before. The big differnce is my anchor is at the bottom and there is content my drawer goes over. If it was a left anchor I understand how to do this. I think I have narrowed down the issues is with the backdrop component, If I could just limit its height to the same of the drawer so the components behind it were able to be used

Comment: Or I was possibly thinking of just changing the z-index of the backdrop components as I already have the invisibility set to true but that's through props, not sure how to add CSS to the that component cause it doesn't looks like its exposed in the api https://material-ui.com/api/drawer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my problem, I ended us having to do some height changes to the Paper component and it seemed to work the way I wanted. You can overrided the css with `makeStyles` method in the `@material-ui/core/styles` directory. I used the classes property example

```
// Outside the component
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  drawer: {
    css here ... 
  }
})
// Inside Component 
const classes = useStyles() // the make styles returns a function and calling the useStyles returns an object with the css. 

// Inside return 
<Drawer
 anchor="bottom" 
 classes={{ paper: classes.drawer }}
>
 Content... 
</Drawer>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it slightly differently, by removing the "inset" CSS property of the `.MuiDrawer-modal` div:

```
.MuiDrawer-modal {
  inset: unset !important;
}
```